# neovim hlsearch not working

Tags: neovim, substitute, highlight, global-command

I'm testing neovim and for many thing it is working way faster than vim (I use many plugins ~80, and I can really tell the difference with neovim). All the same config files worked out of the box, but I've notice this different behavior. `hlsearch` seems not to be working, it does work when I use `/` but not when I use `:g` or `:%s`. Here an example, neovim on the left, vim on the right:

[image]

As it can be observed, in vim the pattern is highlighted which is great. 
Is there a way to activate this behavior in neovim or is this feature missing?

Comment: It shouldn't work with `:g` in either *nvim* or *vim*, but in my system, I do get highlighting for `:s`... Have you tried `:set hlsearch` with `:set incsearch` in a default system (without config)?

Comment: @klaus why shouldn't it work? it's a great feature hehe

Comment: I'm my vim it works with both `:g` and `:s`

Comment: I believe you need `incsearch` to enable live highlighting when entering the search pattern using `:g` and `:s`. The incsearch feature for `:g` and `:s` is a relative recent Vim addition, needs at least 8.1.0271 (and several patches after that). Most likely neovim hasn't included that one yet.